# PHP - My Battery Script Ate all my memory

Tags: php, hibernate, linux-mint

I'm a novice developer who's just started coding about a year ago. I'm currently running Linux Mint 18.1 and I like to keep track of my Laptop's stats via a tmux window with several things open like Htop, Iotop, sensors, etc.

I recently created a battery script with PHP that is successful for viewing what I want but I encountered an error that I'm not sure how to combat. Basically my script outputs battery stats in the terminal window when run and it updates every second. My dilemma is that I put my laptop into hibernate and upon waking I was spammed with out of memory errors while my computer struggled to SIGKILL what I presume to be my rogue script.

Here's an example of the long list of errors located in /var/log/php7.0-fpm.log

[24-Jan-2017 17:49:41] WARNING: [pool www] child 3368 exited on signal 9 (SIGKILL) after 0.007716 seconds from start
[24-Jan-2017 17:49:41] NOTICE: [pool www] child 3370 started

I believe it's because of the way my loop works. What would be a better way to execute such a loop?

```
<?php

$true = 1;

while($true == 1){
    EchoStats();
    sleep(1);
    system('clear');
}

function EchoStats()
{
    $stats = GetBatStats();

    echo "Battery State: " . $stats[0] . "\n";
    echo "Battery Level: " . $stats[1] . "\n";
    if($stats[0] == 'discharging'){
        echo "Battery Time Left: " . $stats[2] . "\n";
    }
    if($stats[0] == 'charging'){
        echo "Time until fully charged: " . $stats[2] . "\n";
    }
}

function GetBatStats()
{
    $battPercent = exec("upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0 | grep 'percentage'");
    $battPercent = IsolateValue($battPercent);

    $battState = exec("upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0 | grep 'state'");
    $battState = IsolateValue($battState);

    if($battState == 'discharging'){
        $battEstTime = exec("upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0 | grep 'time to empty'");
        $battEstTime = IsolateValue($battEstTime);
    }
    if($battState == 'charging'){
        $battEstTime = exec("upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0 | grep 'time to full'");
        $battEstTime = IsolateValue($battEstTime);
    }

    return array($battState,$battPercent,$battEstTime);

}

function IsolateValue($var)
{
    $var = explode(':',$var);
    $var = $var[1];
    $var = str_replace(' ','',$var);
    $var = str_replace('hours',' hours',$var);
    $var = str_replace('minutes',' minutes',$var);

    return $var;
}

?>
```

Comment: You are correct in thinking it is the loop, because it does not hook into any OS events. Instead of using 1 CPU thread running this script, you should fire this script from the O.S. level every second. In other words, get rid of the while loop and use a scheduled event, in Linux referred to as a "cron job".

Comment: Hi Xorifelse! Thanks for responding to my question. I initially considered a cronjob, but those are limited to running once a minute. I technically could live with an update once a minute, but I like how fast this script updates. Maybe there's another solution?

Comment: Well, first thing is to drop PHP... why are you using PHP to run shell-commands? Why not just use a bash-script to run and output?

Comment: php is not the language to use for a perpetually running program

Comment: You got me there @Novice_Developer, cron jobs only run once every minute. The problem occurs that the script is killed when entering hibernation, because PHP is not designed to hook into the O.S. at that level. You could design a simple bash application that does hook up into O.S. events. In Ubuntu that's `systemd`. Meaning, still get rid of the `PHP` while loop and let bash loop it instead. Overall, I still think Python is a better alternative seeing what you specifically want.

Comment: @Xorifelse I think I found a solution. I removed the loop from my script and I now launch it with watch. This updates it every 2.0 seconds and now there's no crazy loop happening with php. I'll hibernate my computer and check it tomorrow morning to see if the same problem happens.

Comment: @Novice_Developer No need, that will work as well.